# How have editions of Bang! been different from previous ones?

Tags: bang, edition-comparison

*Bang!* has had a relatively large number of changes over the years. I know lots of people who are used to a different edition than I am. Often, this means they are used to a different set of rules and a different deck composition. What are the changes in each edition?

---

For the sake of clarity, I mean only the editions having English text. (Italian/English versions are fine but not the versions like French or Czech/Slovak/Polish.)

Whenever an expansion has been *included* in an edition, I'd appreciate it if you would describe any changes from the separately-available expansion or which edition the expansion is.

As far as I'm aware, there are five different editions of *Bang!*, listed below (printings' dates listed in parentheses):

- 1st Edition (2002)
- 2nd Edition (2003, 2005)
- 3rd Edition (2007)
- The Bullet (2007, 2009, 2010)
- 4th Edition (2008)

---

**Note:** *Your answer doesn't have to say all the changes for every edition; it will help even if you just mention a few changes.*

Comment: In the interest of keeping within the scope of a question, full descriptions of the expansion are unnecessary, as are lists of expansions. Both should go in a separate question, please.

Comment: Making this CW in the hopes that the community will integrate future answers into one cohesive whole.

Answer (score 2):

### 2nd Edition

This edition adjusted or clarified a few of the rules (and the matching graphics). The rule changes were:

- The Sheriff can't be put in jail. (1st Edition: Sheriff could be put in jail.)
- Discard *Jail* after you skip one turn. (1st Edition: *Jail* was not discarded until a heart ♥ or diamond ♦ was drawn.)
- When performing a *draw!* for jail, the flipped-over card must be hearts ♥ to get you out of jail. (1st Edition: The flipped-over card could be hearts ♥ *or* diamonds ♦.)
- Sid Ketchum has 4 life points. (1st Edition: Sid Ketchum had 3 life points.)

There were also a few changes in cards' names:

- *Cavallo (Horse)* became *Mustang*
- *Maestrina (Mistress)* became *Cat Balou*
- *Indiani! (Injuns!)* become *Indiani! (Indians!)*

### 3rd Edition

—

### Bang! The Bullet!

This was a compilation release, it contained the 3 expansions released at that point

- High Noon
- Dodge City
- A Fistful of Cards

It also included

- 3 special character cards

  - Uncle Will
  - Johnny Kisch
  - Claus "The Saint"
- 2 additional high noon cards

  - New Identity
  - Handcuffs
- A sheriff's badge

This release contained the 3rd edition of the basic game rules and the 2nd edition of the Dodge City rules.

### 4th Edition

—

Comment: The reason why the *Maestrina (Mistress)* card was changed to *Cat Balou* in the second edition was that "mistress" was a mistranslation of *maestrina*, which should have been translated as "schoolmarm". The unintended connotations of the word "mistress" resulted in the name change to "Cat Balou". (From [the Bang! Cards page on the designer's site](http://www.emilianosciarra.net/ENG/playing_cards.html#top).)